# Why can't we initialize a reference to const int with an rvalue volatile int&&?

Tags: c++, reference

I've written the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

volatile int&& bar()
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    const int& i = bar(); //error: binding of reference to type 'const int' 
                          //to a value of type 'volatile int' drops qualifiers
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b54a5c0f73a3f559)**

But if we replace `int&&` with `int` it works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

volatile int bar()
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    const int& i = bar(); //OK

}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87b7778545007a7e)**

that's not exactly clear. What the Standard says is (`8.5.3/5  [dcl.init.ref]`):

> A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type
>   “cv2 T2” as follows:
>
> — If the reference is an lvalue reference and the
>   initializer expression
>
> - is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2,” or
> - has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type), where T1 is not reference-related to T2,
>     and can be converted to an lvalue of type “cv3 T3,” where “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with 
>     “cv3 T3” 108 (this conversion is selected by enumerating the applicable conversion functions 
>     (13.3.1.6) and choosing the best one through overload resolution (13.3)), then the
>     reference is bound to the initializer expression lvalue in the first
>     case and to the lvalue result of the conversion in the second case
>     (or, in either case, to the appropriate base class subobject of the
>     object).
>
> [...]
>
> — *Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a*
>   *non-volatile const type (i.e., cv1 shall be const), or the reference*
>   *shall be an rvalue reference.*

Well, in the first example we have an rvalue of type `volatile int&&`. And the `'otherwise'` case is applicable to both two examples. But `5/5 [expr]` says:

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” (8.3.2,
>   8.5.3), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis

So, essentially we have an rvalue of type `volatile int` instead of `volatile int&&`, which means both these two examples shall work in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two cases is that in Case 1, the references *binds directly* and in Case 2, it does not bind directly (i.e. the reference binds to a temporary; definition can be found in  the last paragraph of `[dcl.init.ref]`).

The direct binding fails because *T2* is volatile-qualified and *T1* isn't (in the Standard terminology, *T1* is not *reference-compatible* with *T2*).

The indirect binding succeeds because when a temporary `int` is initialized from the reference returned by `bar()`, the temporary is not `volatile`. (The temporary has type *cv1 T1*).

---

To see why Case 1 is a direct binding. Firstly, `bar()` is an **xvalue** here. See `[basic.lval]/1` "The result of calling a function whose return type is an rvalue reference is an xvalue".

From `[dcl.init.ref]/5`:

> - If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression [is an lvalue] or [has class type]

Not applicable: the initializer is an xvalue (not an lvalue), and it is a reference so it does not have class type.

> - Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., cv1 shall be const), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference

This does apply: `const int &` is an lvalue reference to non-volatile const type. Going down this tree:

> If the initializer expression
>
> - is an xvalue (but not a bit-field), class prvalue, array prvalue or function lvalue and “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2”, or
> - [another case]
>
> then the reference is bound to the value of the initializer expression in the first case [...]

This does apply because `bar()` is an xvalue. So the reference is bound to the xvalue and this is known as *direct binding* because it is not bound to a temporary.

---

NB. All Standard references are from C++14 (N3936) . This section changed from C++11 due to DR1288.

Comment: Plus, if Im not mistaken, the returned rvalue in this case would be a dangling reference because the temp from which the reference is create is destroyed right after the assignment i = bar(); Why not just return by value and let either the compiler optimize (elision) or the use the move constructor?

Comment: @victor I believe he is writing his own compiler and therefore needs to understand all these weird cases

Comment: _In your second example, bar() is a prvalue; in the first example it is an xvalue._ It's not quite clear. How do you distinguish these?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv `bar()` is an xvalue if `bar` is a function that returns an rvalue reference. see [basic.lval]/1

Comment: I got it. Thank you. Could you possibly provide a refernce descibes _xvalues bind directly to lvalue references; prvalues don't._?

Comment: It is in dcl.init.ref, I'll try to update my post to make it clearer

Comment: @victor I think the reference is dangling as soon as the line `const int &i = bar();` finishes

Comment: @MattMcNabb that's what I said: "destroyed right after the assignment i = bar();", which is when the temp object is destroyed :) Im not 100% sure tho, but I think it makes sense.

Comment: @victor actually on further checking it's destroyed as soon as the function returns (earlier than we were saying)

Comment: There is a question on this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322089/const-and-volatile-are-reference-compatible