# Const and Volatile are reference compatible?

Tags: c++

I am asking this question due to having confusion in the accepted answer for the below question:

[Why can't we initialize a reference to `const int` with an rvalue `volatile int&&`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857674/why-cant-we-initialize-a-reference-to-const-int-with-an-rvalue-volatile-int?rq=1)

For case 1 in the question stated there , How come it should go in the following section mentioned in standard:

> If the initializer expression is an xvalue (but not a bit-field), class prvalue, array prvalue or function lvalue and “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2”, or

According to my knowledge it should not come to this section because xvalue returned by `volatile int && bar()` is of volatile type and `const int &` is not reference compatible with `volatile` xvalue and thus it should go to the very last part of reference initialization and that is the same as of case 2 and temporary should be created and case 1 should also be passed as case2 .

Please help me to clarify this.

Comment: It is the answer by M.M in the linked question